# How do I increase the percentage in an area?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

I noticed that the Default Village has a percentage that shows up on the map. I am not sure what this means - I thought it might have something to do with quest completion, but I seemingly keep getting more and more quests there, and I haven't hit 100% yet.

Does this have to do with completing different types of quests? Or is it relating to something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, it means the percentage of quest completion. Once it is not 100%, it means that there are new quests there (which can appear after completing a quest somewhere else).